# How to get the pk of a post in which a comment is contained?

Tags: django, django-templates

In my code, I have an "add comment" option on my posts, but am struggling to make a cancel button for the create comment form as I keep getting a NoReverseMatch error.  I'm trying to just have the cancel button be a link back to the post instead of anything too fancy, but it doesn't seem to recognize the URL I'm giving it.  It's supposed to be a link to my posts, while calling the pk of the post that contained the comment.

I've been trying to make some kind of workarounds, including a designated cancel function, trying to pull info from the URL, etc. but just can't see what I'm doing wrong.  Even more puzzling is that the template related to CommentCreateView doesn't work, but the one related to CommentUpdateView does even though they're the exact same.  I've included the relevant code below, and I'm new to django so please let me know if there's anything else that would be helpful to include.  Thank you!

error message:

```
NoReverseMatch at /post/29/comment/

Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

views.py:

```
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['text']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        post_number = Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return post_number.get_absolute_url()

class CommentUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['text']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user.username
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.username == self.get_object().author

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.get_object().post.pk})
```

models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

urls.py

```
path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', CommentCreateView.as_view(template_name="blog/comments/comment_form.html"), name='add-comment-to-post'),
path('comment/<int:pk>/update/', CommentUpdateView.as_view(template_name="blog/comments/comment_update_form.html"), name='comment-update'),  # Update comment
```

comment_form.html (this seems to be the problem, caused by 'post-detail'.  when I take out object.post.id and hardcode in '29' which is the pk of the post I've been testing on, it works fine.  obviously this is not a solution though.):

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
<a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="{% url 'post-detail' object.post.id %}">Cancel</a>
```

comment_update_form.html (the template that works):

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
<a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="{% url 'post-detail' object.post.id %}">Cancel</a>
```

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`comment_update_form.html` works because the object in that rendered template has been saved already and contains a `post` foreign key, so `object.post.id` resolves to something. This is not the case in `comment_form.html`. The 'object' in that template does not exist yet and so cannot have a `post` attribute.

You will need to find another way to resolve the url in the template - perhaps you could use `view.kwargs.pk` if you are not inserting the post pk into your template in any other way.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just accepted your answer!  I changed object.post.id to view.kwargs.pk and it worked perfectly.  For further understanding though, could you possibly explain what view.kwargs.pk is specifically referencing?  And also would it be possible to ask if there would be some way to save the object in the rendered template for comment_form.html?  As in, where does the update class save the object but the comment view doesn't?

Comment: `view` in the template refers to the view instance (in this case `CommentCreateView`, which has an attribute called `kwargs`, which is a dictionary of the url parameters. Your url has a parameter `pk` which is the id of the post. You can't save an object in a template, you save the object in the view, which is the purpose of CreateView. The template is simply to enter the data so the object can be saved in the view. Both the update and create views save the object; but in the case of the update view, the object *has already been saved*, so you're working with an existing instance.

Comment: Ohhh I see ok.  One of the things I tried was referencing `CommentCreateView` in my template but I didn't realize I just needed to use `views` instead.  I also didn't even think about the fact that the object is already saved in update views because the comment has been submitted.  Thank you again, that really clarified so many things for me!